# Liferay Client Side IPC - Call back

Tags: liferay, ipc

I want to use a call back function with Liferay.fire which comes into action once the event fired by one portlet is caught by another and worked upon.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have already gone through below wiki's, If not You can go through below Wiki having some basic..

https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Client-side+Inter-Portlet+Communication

https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Portlet+to+Portlet+Communication

If run into specific problem you can share it.

Comment: I have gone through those wikis what I wanted was s thing like 
        Liferay.fire("eventName", "data", callback function)